# Ubuntu Server CPU Spiking

Tags: ubuntu, cpu, webserver, ubuntu-18.04

I am currently running an Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS VPS

Recently my server CPU has spiked to around 98-99%, which is causing my website etc to go offline.

I have run a virus scan and it has come back clean

I have spoken to my hosting provider and they have told me that they cannot check back to see what has caused the issue.

I am finding that the issue is becoming more frequent. It started happening, maybe once per week, it is not happening once every 1-2 days

I was wondering if there was a recommended way to monitor the CPU to identify what might be causing the issue.

I have installed `atop` today and will check this after the next spike.

Are there any other recommended monitoring programs which might help pinpoint the cause?

[image]

Comment: What platform is the site histed in?  What monitoring do you have in place? Are you logging page viewd (if so, can you corrolate spukes with activity/pagrs?).  Is your CPU spukung ir your load? (Very different things).  Are you running a backend Database?  If si, are you logging slow queries?

Comment: @davidgo I use Ionos Ubunto 18.04 VPS. Monitoring wise I have installed `atop` but only recently as I thought Ionos would have had their own reporting tools. The CPU and RAM both appear to spike at the same time, I have added a screenshot above. I dont know how to log slow queries. I am by no means a server expert, I ma self taught with most things and pick most things up as I go along

Comment: What are you running on the VPS? Have you looked through /var/log/* for messages?  How many vcpu's do you have?

Comment: @davidgo I have looked at `/vat/log/syslog.1` and I noticed that there are a number of entries similar to :-

Comment: `Jun 20 11:33:26 server postfix/smtpd[35671]: connect from unknown[87.246.7.230]`
`Jun 20 11:33:34 server plesk_saslauthd[35824]: No such user 's41@co.uk' in mail authorization database`
`Jun 20 11:33:34 server plesk_saslauthd[35824]: failed mail authentication attempt for user 's41@co.uk' (password len=9)`
`Jun 20 11:33:34 server postfix/smtpd[35671]: warning: unknown[87.246.7.230]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure`

Comment: `Jun 20 11:33:36 server postfix/smtpd[35671]: disconnect from unknown[87.246.7.230] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 rset=1 quit=1 commands=3/4`
`Jun 20 11:33:40 server postfix/smtpd[36870]: warning: hostname net6-ip230.linkbg.com does not resolve to address 87.246.7.230: Name or service not known
`

Comment: Each time there is a different user in the line `Jun 20 11:33:34 server plesk_saslauthd[35824]: No such user 's41@co.uk' in mail authorization database `

Comment: What are you running a mail server for?  If you are only sending emails from it, it is incorrectly set up as it appears to be allowing inbound connections - it is possible that someone is trying to brute-force an email login so they can use it as an open relay.   You might want to look closely at your mail log files and see if you are getting bursts of activity, and if so, ratelimit and/or use fail2ban if you can't simply prevent incoming SMTP connections altogether.

Comment: Of-course, this might be a red herring - and unless your system is very resource constrained or there is a large burst of attempts this may be coincidental - I guess it depends how closely these attempts align with your peak bursts.

Comment: @davidgo So it looks like a hacking attempt rather than a problem with software?

Comment: I don't have enough information to say - I'm just reflecting back to you what you advised from your logs.   Are you actually using that server to receive email?   If not, the simplest way to check is to just block incoming email and see if the problem goes away (eg with a rule "iptables -I INPUT -t tcp --dport 25 -j DROP" - and that is good for your systems security too.